# Construct a circle contains all n-bit binary number

Tags: algorithm

The problem comes from an interview: 
How to construct a circle (01 round sequences with length 2^n) contains all possible n-bit binary number, each number appears once and only once. For example, when n=2, the result is:

```
0--0
|  |
1--1
```

the numbers are {00, 01, 11, 10}. All possible numbers appear once and only once. When n=3, here is an example answer:

```
  0--0--1
 /       \
0         1
 \       /  
  1--0--1
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Can you update your question and add an example where n=3?

Comment: can't you just iterate over all the posible numbers, and just print them in bitset?

Comment: OK, I've added when n=3

Answer (score 5):

You need to construct binary [de Bruijn cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). Wikipedia article suggests several ways to do it:

> The De Bruijn sequences can be constructed by taking a Hamiltonian path of an n-dimensional De Bruijn graph over k symbols (or equivalently, a Eulerian cycle of a (n − 1)-dimensional De Bruijn graph).
>
> An alternative construction involves concatenating together, in lexicographic order, all the Lyndon words whose length divides n.
>
> De Bruijn sequences can also be constructed using shift registers or via finite fields.

Answer (score 5):

Linear Shift Feedback Registers come handy in generating this sequence:

Starting with 001, generate the 7 next bits using LSFR with polynomial p(x) = 101.
The sequence would be '001 1101 001'. (The period of LSFR is 2^N - 1, with the all-zero entry missing.)

Noticing that the same 3-bit sequence occurs in both ends, we'll replace the last sequence with a zero -- '00111010'.

The offsets where the numbers 0..7 occur are 7, 0, 5, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2.

The polynomial is applied by xoring all the bits of the previous N-bit entry where the polynomial has a one.

```
    0 0 1
xor 1 0 1 => (0 and 1) xor (0 and 0) xor (1 and 1) => 1

    0 0 1 1
xor   1 0 1 ==> (0 and 1) xor (1 and 0) xor (1 and 1) => 1
```

As a generic rule, the polynomial has a 1 on both ends, and some number of ones in the middle; one can try to brute force search the missing bits or google for "primitive polynomials in galois field" for a comprehensive list.

Comment: (0 and 1) means 0&1 ?